# How to pass EditText value in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, textview

MainActivity.java

```
EditText t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText); 
String str=t.getText().toString(); 
this.getSharedPreferences("mp", 
     Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("pt",str).apply();
```

Receiver.java

```
    TextView t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); 
    String s = this.getSharedPreferences("mp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("pt","");
    t.setText(s);
```

In this when I'm passing string values directly instead of `EditText` data it works well. 
Please fix where's the mistake.
*thanks in advance*

Comment: Give us more than just those lines of code. Paste the entire method or even the class. Where is the code executed? Is it onCreate? Is it onResume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called these functions in `onCreate` function. You should put theme in a button's listener

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    private void onClick(View view){
        // get text from EditText
        // put text to SharedPreferences
    }
});
```

When application started, there is nothing in your `EditText`.